# iPhone: How to send httprequest via button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

There is 1 button on a view screen, when the user clicks the button a httprequest is sent to 
http://domain.com/buttoninput.php?id=1

Thats it! Nothing is loaded on the screen! the page is only loaded in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
// URL string  encoding

```
NSString *escapedUrl = [aURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

// create the request

```
 NSURLRequest *aRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrl]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

// create the connection with the request 
  // and start loading the data

```
NSURLConnection *aConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:aRequest delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably (at least you should) load the data asynchronously. Upon finishing (your delegate methods are your best friends) evaluate the data your received and change your UI elements. Why would you expect anything to update automatically?